# Landscape ignoring available column if abstract is too long

Tags: tables

As you can see below, when I use the `landscape` environment to rotate a page or a table, the second column of the page above is ignored and left empty. How can I pull up the remaining text and the section titled **Risk of Bias** to the column above the landscape page and allow text to flow freely around the landscaped page?

Here is some dummy code that represents my text now:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\newcommand{\passosic}{low surgical risk with uncomplicated cholecysitis}
\newcommand{\passosec}{renal or hepatic impairment; \newline immunosuppression}
\newcommand{\darziic}{1st time abdominal surgery}
\newcommand{\darziec}{immunocompromise; \newline DM; \newline previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP within 1 week of surgery}
\newcommand{\matsuiic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\matsuiec}{regular insulin or steroid use; \newline on HD; \newline severe comorbidities such as Child C liver cirrhosis; \newline receiving chemotherapy}
\newcommand{\ruangsinic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\ruangsinec}{previous biliary tract surgery; \newline prosthetic heart valve; \newline concomitant infection; \newline single port procedure}
\newcommand{\turkic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\turkec}{$\geq$ ASA 3; \newline previous biliary tract surgery; \newline pre-op WBC $>$ 12.5}
\newcommand{\naqviic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\naqviec}{high risk of infection (i.e. DM, steroid use, immunosuppression)}
\newcommand{\hassanic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\hassanec}{prosthetic valves/joints; \newline DM; \newline high risk of infection (undefined); \newline pregnant or lactating}
\newcommand{\sharmaic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\sharmaec}{immunosuppression; \newline cardiac disorders requiring prophylactic antibiotics}
\newcommand{\uludagic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\uludagec}{previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP; \newline $\geq$ ASA 3; \newline DM; \newline BMI $>$ 30}
\newcommand{\yildizic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\yildizec}{previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP; \newline prosthetic valves; \newline chronic hepatic disease; \newline immunosuppression}
\newcommand{\kutheic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\kutheec}{prosthetic valves; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline regular steroid use}
\newcommand{\kocic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\kocec}{prosthetic valves; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline pre-op WBC $>$ 12.5; \newline chronic hepatic disease; \newline high risk of infection (undefinded)}
\newcommand{\mahaic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\mahaec}{prosthetic valves; \newline immunosuppression; \newline pregnant or lactating}
\newcommand{\tocchiic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\tocchiec}{previous biliary duct surgery; \newline prosthetic valves; \newline regular steroid use}
\newcommand{\higginsic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\higginsec}{previous biliary duct surgery; \newline prosthetic valves or joints; \newline high risk of infection (undefined)}
\newcommand{\mahmoudic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\mahmoudec}{DM; \newline regular steroid use; \newline previous biliary duct surgery}
\newcommand{\kumaric}{N/A}
\newcommand{\kumarec}{prosthetic valves or joints; \newline DM; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline pregnant or lactating}

\newcommand{\absdiv}[1]{%
    \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}% adjust to suit
    \noindent\textbf{#1}\quad\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \author{Fake author}
        \date{\today}
        \title{Fake title\\
            \large Fake subtitle}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \absdiv{Introduction} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            \absdiv{Methods} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            \absdiv{Results} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

            \absdiv{Conclusion} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

        \end{abstract}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]


\section*{Introduction} 
\lipsum
\section*{Methods}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of studies}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of participants}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of interventions}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Outcome measures}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Search strategy}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Data collection}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Assessment of risk of bias}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Data analysis}
\lipsum
\section*{Results}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Study Selection}
\lipsum 
\subsection*{Study Characteristics}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\afterpage{
    \begin{landscape}
        \centering
        \begin{table}
            \begin{scriptsize}
                {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
                    \begin{tabular}{l c c m{5cm} m{2cm} m{3cm} m{8cm}}
                        \textbf{Study} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{Prophylaxis} & \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Inclusion criteria} & \textbf{Exclusion criteria}  \\
                        \hline
                        Passos 2016        & 50  & 50  & Cefazolin 2g IV during anesthesia & None                                  & \passosic & \passosec \\\hline
                        Darzi 2016         & 182 & 247 & Cefazolin 1g IV 30min prior to anesthesia; every 6 hours after anesthesia 
                        & NaCl                                                                                 & \darziic & \darziec \\\hline
                        Matsui 2014        & 504 & 505 & Cefazolin 1g IV at skin incision; at 12 and 24 hours post-incision & None & \matsuiic & \matsuiec \\\hline
                        Ruangsin 2015      & 150 & 149 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \ruangsinic & \ruangsinec \\\hline
                        Turk 2013          & 278 & 269 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \turkic & \turkec \\\hline
                        Naqvi 2013         & 177 & 173 & Cefuroxime 1.5g IV during anesthesia & None                               & \naqviic & \naqviec \\\hline
                        Hassan 2012        & 100 & 100 & Ceftazidime IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                   & \hassanic & \hassanec \\\hline
                        Sharma 2010        & 50  & 50  & Ceftriaxone 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                & \sharmaic & \sharmaic \\\hline
                        Uludag 2009        & 68  & 76  & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \uludagic & \uludagec \\\hline
                        Yildiz 2009        & 105 & 103 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \yildizic & \yildizec \\\hline
                        Kuthe 2006         & 40  & 53  & Cefuroxime 1.5g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                               & \kutheic & \kutheec \\\hline
                        Koc 2003           & 49  & 43  & Cefotaxime 2g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                 & \kocic & \kocec \\\hline
                        Mahatharadol 2001  & 50  & 50  & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia  & None                                 & \mahaic  & \mahaec  \\\hline
                        Tocchi 2000        & 44  & 40  & Cefotaxime 2g IV 30 min before anesthesia; 24 hours after surgery & NaCl  & \tocchiic & \tocchiec \\\hline
                        Higgins 1999       & 277 & 135 & Cefotetan 1g IV or Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl               & \higginsic & \higginsec \\\hline
                        Mahmoud 2005       & 29  & 35  & Cefotaxime 2g IV 30 min before anesthesia & NaCl                          & \mahmoudic & \mahmoudec \\\hline
                        Kumar 2012         & 50  & 48  & Ceftriaxone 1g IV 30 min before anesthesia & NaCl                         & \kumaric   & \kumarec \\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                }% ends arraystretch
            \end{scriptsize}
            \caption{Study characteristics}
            \label{table:studychar}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
} % ends afterpage


\subsection*{Risk of Bias}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here is some dummy code that demonstrates how it works as expected **if the abstract is shortened**

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\newcommand{\passosic}{low surgical risk with uncomplicated cholecysitis}
\newcommand{\passosec}{renal or hepatic impairment; \newline immunosuppression}
\newcommand{\darziic}{1st time abdominal surgery}
\newcommand{\darziec}{immunocompromise; \newline DM; \newline previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP within 1 week of surgery}
\newcommand{\matsuiic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\matsuiec}{regular insulin or steroid use; \newline on HD; \newline severe comorbidities such as Child C liver cirrhosis; \newline receiving chemotherapy}
\newcommand{\ruangsinic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\ruangsinec}{previous biliary tract surgery; \newline prosthetic heart valve; \newline concomitant infection; \newline single port procedure}
\newcommand{\turkic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\turkec}{$\geq$ ASA 3; \newline previous biliary tract surgery; \newline pre-op WBC $>$ 12.5}
\newcommand{\naqviic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\naqviec}{high risk of infection (i.e. DM, steroid use, immunosuppression)}
\newcommand{\hassanic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\hassanec}{prosthetic valves/joints; \newline DM; \newline high risk of infection (undefined); \newline pregnant or lactating}
\newcommand{\sharmaic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\sharmaec}{immunosuppression; \newline cardiac disorders requiring prophylactic antibiotics}
\newcommand{\uludagic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\uludagec}{previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP; \newline $\geq$ ASA 3; \newline DM; \newline BMI $>$ 30}
\newcommand{\yildizic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\yildizec}{previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP; \newline prosthetic valves; \newline chronic hepatic disease; \newline immunosuppression}
\newcommand{\kutheic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\kutheec}{prosthetic valves; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline regular steroid use}
\newcommand{\kocic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\kocec}{prosthetic valves; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline pre-op WBC $>$ 12.5; \newline chronic hepatic disease; \newline high risk of infection (undefinded)}
\newcommand{\mahaic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\mahaec}{prosthetic valves; \newline immunosuppression; \newline pregnant or lactating}
\newcommand{\tocchiic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\tocchiec}{previous biliary duct surgery; \newline prosthetic valves; \newline regular steroid use}
\newcommand{\higginsic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\higginsec}{previous biliary duct surgery; \newline prosthetic valves or joints; \newline high risk of infection (undefined)}
\newcommand{\mahmoudic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\mahmoudec}{DM; \newline regular steroid use; \newline previous biliary duct surgery}
\newcommand{\kumaric}{N/A}
\newcommand{\kumarec}{prosthetic valves or joints; \newline DM; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline pregnant or lactating}

\newcommand{\absdiv}[1]{%
    \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}% adjust to suit
    \noindent\textbf{#1}\quad\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}

    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \author{Fake author}
        \date{\today}
        \title{Fake title\\
            \large Fake subtitle}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \absdiv{Introduction}

            \absdiv{Methods} 

            \absdiv{Results} 

            \absdiv{Conclusion} 

        \end{abstract}
        \vspace{1cm}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]


\section*{Introduction} 
\lipsum
\section*{Methods}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of studies}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of participants}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of interventions}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Outcome measures}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Search strategy}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Data collection}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Assessment of risk of bias}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Data analysis}
\lipsum
\section*{Results}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Study Selection}
\lipsum 
\subsection*{Study Characteristics}
\lipsum
\lipsum

\afterpage{
    \begin{landscape}
        \centering
        \begin{table}
            \begin{scriptsize}
                {\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
                    \begin{tabular}{l c c m{5cm} m{2cm} m{3cm} m{8cm}}
                        \textbf{Study} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{Prophylaxis} & \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Inclusion criteria} & \textbf{Exclusion criteria}  \\
                        \hline
                        Passos 2016        & 50  & 50  & Cefazolin 2g IV during anesthesia & None                                  & \passosic & \passosec \\\hline
                        Darzi 2016         & 182 & 247 & Cefazolin 1g IV 30min prior to anesthesia; every 6 hours after anesthesia 
                        & NaCl                                                                                 & \darziic & \darziec \\\hline
                        Matsui 2014        & 504 & 505 & Cefazolin 1g IV at skin incision; at 12 and 24 hours post-incision & None & \matsuiic & \matsuiec \\\hline
                        Ruangsin 2015      & 150 & 149 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \ruangsinic & \ruangsinec \\\hline
                        Turk 2013          & 278 & 269 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \turkic & \turkec \\\hline
                        Naqvi 2013         & 177 & 173 & Cefuroxime 1.5g IV during anesthesia & None                               & \naqviic & \naqviec \\\hline
                        Hassan 2012        & 100 & 100 & Ceftazidime IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                   & \hassanic & \hassanec \\\hline
                        Sharma 2010        & 50  & 50  & Ceftriaxone 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                & \sharmaic & \sharmaic \\\hline
                        Uludag 2009        & 68  & 76  & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \uludagic & \uludagec \\\hline
                        Yildiz 2009        & 105 & 103 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \yildizic & \yildizec \\\hline
                        Kuthe 2006         & 40  & 53  & Cefuroxime 1.5g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                               & \kutheic & \kutheec \\\hline
                        Koc 2003           & 49  & 43  & Cefotaxime 2g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                 & \kocic & \kocec \\\hline
                        Mahatharadol 2001  & 50  & 50  & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia  & None                                 & \mahaic  & \mahaec  \\\hline
                        Tocchi 2000        & 44  & 40  & Cefotaxime 2g IV 30 min before anesthesia; 24 hours after surgery & NaCl  & \tocchiic & \tocchiec \\\hline
                        Higgins 1999       & 277 & 135 & Cefotetan 1g IV or Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl               & \higginsic & \higginsec \\\hline
                        Mahmoud 2005       & 29  & 35  & Cefotaxime 2g IV 30 min before anesthesia & NaCl                          & \mahmoudic & \mahmoudec \\\hline
                        Kumar 2012         & 50  & 48  & Ceftriaxone 1g IV 30 min before anesthesia & NaCl                         & \kumaric   & \kumarec \\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}
                }% ends arraystretch
            \end{scriptsize}
            \caption{Study characteristics}
            \label{table:studychar}
        \end{table}
    \end{landscape}
} % ends afterpage


\subsection*{Risk of Bias}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Can anyone suggest a fix to make it work as expected with a longer abstract?

[image: example]

By the way, if you happen to have any suggestions for making my table more readable or  better looking, please let me know. I'm a novice with tables.

Comment: Please provide full MWE

Comment: What is that exactly?

Comment: Working example that we can compile and get output

Comment: Updated. I actually figured out what was causing it but I don't know how to fix it. For whatever reason, shortening the abstract address the weird column skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had to use `\afterpage{..` then the solution would be to simply move it further down the source file so that some text started to flow into the right hand column, and the `\afterpage` mechanism would fill that column before inserting the landscape page.

However a better solution is not to use `landcape` or `\afterpage` (a double bonus of two of my packages removed:-) and to use a floating `sidewaystable`

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.7in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array,multirow}

\newcommand{\passosic}{low surgical risk with uncomplicated cholecysitis}
\newcommand{\passosec}{renal or hepatic impairment; \newline immunosuppression}
\newcommand{\darziic}{1st time abdominal surgery}
\newcommand{\darziec}{immunocompromise; \newline DM; \newline previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP within 1 week of surgery}
\newcommand{\matsuiic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\matsuiec}{regular insulin or steroid use; \newline on HD; \newline severe comorbidities such as Child C liver cirrhosis; \newline receiving chemotherapy}
\newcommand{\ruangsinic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\ruangsinec}{previous biliary tract surgery; \newline prosthetic heart valve; \newline concomitant infection; \newline single port procedure}
\newcommand{\turkic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\turkec}{$\geq$ ASA 3; \newline previous biliary tract surgery; \newline pre-op WBC $>$ 12.5}
\newcommand{\naqviic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\naqviec}{high risk of infection (i.e. DM, steroid use, immunosuppression)}
\newcommand{\hassanic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\hassanec}{prosthetic valves/joints; \newline DM; \newline high risk of infection (undefined); \newline pregnant or lactating}
\newcommand{\sharmaic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\sharmaec}{immunosuppression; \newline cardiac disorders requiring prophylactic antibiotics}
\newcommand{\uludagic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\uludagec}{previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP; \newline $\geq$ ASA 3; \newline DM; \newline BMI $>$ 30}
\newcommand{\yildizic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\yildizec}{previous biliary duct surgery or ERCP; \newline prosthetic valves; \newline chronic hepatic disease; \newline immunosuppression}
\newcommand{\kutheic}{ASA 1 or ASA 2}
\newcommand{\kutheec}{prosthetic valves; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline regular steroid use}
\newcommand{\kocic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\kocec}{prosthetic valves; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline pre-op WBC $>$ 12.5; \newline chronic hepatic disease; \newline high risk of infection (undefinded)}
\newcommand{\mahaic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\mahaec}{prosthetic valves; \newline immunosuppression; \newline pregnant or lactating}
\newcommand{\tocchiic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\tocchiec}{previous biliary duct surgery; \newline prosthetic valves; \newline regular steroid use}
\newcommand{\higginsic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\higginsec}{previous biliary duct surgery; \newline prosthetic valves or joints; \newline high risk of infection (undefined)}
\newcommand{\mahmoudic}{N/A}
\newcommand{\mahmoudec}{DM; \newline regular steroid use; \newline previous biliary duct surgery}
\newcommand{\kumaric}{N/A}
\newcommand{\kumarec}{prosthetic valves or joints; \newline DM; \newline previous biliary duct surgery; \newline pregnant or lactating}


\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction} 
\lipsum
\section*{Methods}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of studies}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of participants}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Types of interventions}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Outcome measures}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Search strategy}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Data collection}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Assessment of risk of bias}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Data analysis}
\lipsum
\section*{Results}
\lipsum
\subsection*{Study Selection}
\lipsum 
\subsection*{Study Characteristics}

\lipsum[1]


        \begin{sidewaystable*}
            \scriptsize
                \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}%
                    \begin{tabular}{l c c m{5cm} m{2cm} m{3cm} m{8cm}}
                        \textbf{Study} & \textbf{P} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{Prophylaxis} & \textbf{Control} & \textbf{Inclusion criteria} & \textbf{Exclusion criteria}  \\
                        \hline
                        Passos 2016        & 50  & 50  & Cefazolin 2g IV during anesthesia & None                                  & \passosic & \passosec \\\hline
                        Darzi 2016         & 182 & 247 & Cefazolin 1g IV 30min prior to anesthesia; every 6 hours after anesthesia 
                        & NaCl                                                                                 & \darziic & \darziec \\\hline
                        Matsui 2014        & 504 & 505 & Cefazolin 1g IV at skin incision; at 12 and 24 hours post-incision & None & \matsuiic & \matsuiec \\\hline
                        Ruangsin 2015      & 150 & 149 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \ruangsinic & \ruangsinec \\\hline
                        Turk 2013          & 278 & 269 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \turkic & \turkec \\\hline
                        Naqvi 2013         & 177 & 173 & Cefuroxime 1.5g IV during anesthesia & None                               & \naqviic & \naqviec \\\hline
                        Hassan 2012        & 100 & 100 & Ceftazidime IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                   & \hassanic & \hassanec \\\hline
                        Sharma 2010        & 50  & 50  & Ceftriaxone 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                & \sharmaic & \sharmaic \\\hline
                        Uludag 2009        & 68  & 76  & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \uludagic & \uludagec \\\hline
                        Yildiz 2009        & 105 & 103 & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                  & \yildizic & \yildizec \\\hline
                        Kuthe 2006         & 40  & 53  & Cefuroxime 1.5g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                               & \kutheic & \kutheec \\\hline
                        Koc 2003           & 49  & 43  & Cefotaxime 2g IV during anesthesia & NaCl                                 & \kocic & \kocec \\\hline
                        Mahatharadol 2001  & 50  & 50  & Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia  & None                                 & \mahaic  & \mahaec  \\\hline
                        Tocchi 2000        & 44  & 40  & Cefotaxime 2g IV 30 min before anesthesia; 24 hours after surgery & NaCl  & \tocchiic & \tocchiec \\\hline
                        Higgins 1999       & 277 & 135 & Cefotetan 1g IV or Cefazolin 1g IV during anesthesia & NaCl               & \higginsic & \higginsec \\\hline
                        Mahmoud 2005       & 29  & 35  & Cefotaxime 2g IV 30 min before anesthesia & NaCl                          & \mahmoudic & \mahmoudec \\\hline
                        Kumar 2012         & 50  & 48  & Ceftriaxone 1g IV 30 min before anesthesia & NaCl                         & \kumaric   & \kumarec \\
                        \hline
                    \end{tabular}



            \caption{Study characteristics}
            \label{table:studychar}
        \end{sidewaystable*}



\subsection*{Risk of Bias}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! You don't have any advice for "making the table look any better" do you? Superfluous to the question I asked, but still always looking to improve the appearance of my manuscripts.